# Constructor on type 'Track_Attack.TAGeneric' not found. C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I'm getting a warning message in Visual Studio 2010 (the one in the title)

Basically I've made a generic form which has a bunch of variables, virtual functions.

It takes a class I made as a parameter and assigns it to a local variable (which is then put as a propety using getters and setters)

I then made another form which inherits from this form. All is well, it runs, but when I attempt to look at the designer of it, I get that error message.

```
    public TAGeneric(TAManager iManager)
    {
        ControlHelper.SuspendDrawing(this);

        mManager = iManager;

        SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer |
            ControlStyles.UserPaint |
            ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);

        InitializeComponent();
        SetupCommandBar();
        ControlHelper.ResumeDrawing(this);
    }
```

Thats the parent.

```
    public TAAddInterval(TAManager iManager) : base(iManager)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

This is a child. Forget the fact I'm using a "manager" when it is frowned upon. Anyone shed some light on the problem? Literally works fine to run, but when it comes to trying to edit the graphical side in designer, It won't load it.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, I would recommend changing the name "Generic" in your class to something else because [Generic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172192.aspx) actually means something in .Net.

Comment: Find a MS support: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/893709

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect you need to provide a parameterless constructor for the designer to use:

```
public TAAddInterval(TAManager iManager) : base(iManager)
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

[Obsolete("This constructor only exists for the benefit of the designer...")]
public TAAddInterval() : this(null)
{
}
```

If you have some sort of fake `TAManager` you could provide instead, that might avoid `NullReferenceException` being thrown if the designer happens to hit some code which uses the manager.

Comment: Took the words right out of my mouth! +1 for a Jon Skeet answer!

Comment: So I add the second constructor in my child form along with the original ?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I tried the code you provided, but it still gives me the same message :(

Comment: @ICTech: Are you sure you're trying to add the *child* class to the designer, not the parent?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Not sure if I quite understand what you mean. The designer is for the child form. The parent form has no problems at all.

Comment: @ICTech: Well the error message you've shown sounds like it's about the parent...

Comment: Fixed it! Thanks for the help, it was the parent and some weird behaviour from one of my custom components that I manually draw. I added an empty constructor in the parent class, this seem to sort it out.

Answer (score 2):

You likely just need a parameterless constructor and the designer will work fine.

Comment: In my parent or child ? or both ?

Comment: Well, for the designer to work, every form needs to have a parameterless constructor. Even if that constructor just inherits from it's base. If you take @JonSkeet example one level down you can implement a parameterless constructor that then inherits from the base (either constructor).